# Creating TEMP TABLE dynamically in Postgresql and selecting the same table in FOR loop. But getting the error near PIPE symbol

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

```
do
$xyz$
declare
y text;
i record;
begin
y := to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS');
raise notice '%',y;
execute 'CREATE TEMP TABLE someNewTable' 
  ||y
  ||' AS select * from ( VALUES(0::int,-99999::numeric), (1::int,       100::numeric)) as t (key, value)';

    for i in (select * from someNewTable||y) loop
     raise notice '%',i.key;
    end loop;
   end;
  $xyz$ language 'plpgsql'


 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "||"
LINE 13:    for i in (select * from someNewTable||y) loop
```

Im unable to understand why the error is at the PIPE symbol. Please help me. I have been trying in Oracle db too, but same error. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Please post the Oracle code to get help about Oracle. If the question only is about Postgres, please remove the Oracle tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query in `for ... loop` statement also has to be dynamic, so you should use `execute` twice.

Use the [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function which is very convenient in conjunction with `execute`:

```
do $xyz$
declare
    y text;
    i record;
begin
    y := to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS');
    raise notice '%', y;
    execute format($ex$
        create temp table somenewtable%s
        as select * from (
            values
                (0::int, -99999::numeric), 
                (1::int, 100::numeric)
            ) as t (key, value)
        $ex$, y);

    for i in 
        execute format($ex$
            select * from somenewtable%s
            $ex$, y)
    loop
        raise notice '%',i.key;
    end loop;
end;
$xyz$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: Thanks Klin. I found the answer (format()) half hour later I posted here. Really appreciate your effort. :)